# Relocate ASP.NET MVC4 Views directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project, I want to regroup the Models/Views/Controllers folders inside a `MVC/` folder, to cleanup the project's root.

I learned how to change the lookup path in the engine to make it work on runtime but when I right-click on a controller's method > Add View, it keeps creating the new view in `Views/<ControllerName>/`.

So I wonder if there an alternative to `Areas` because I only need:

```
MVC/
    Controllers/
    Models/
    Views/
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify scaffolding in mvc.net You can see [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx) post or simple search in google

Comment: Thanks, that gives me some clues to dig :)